# HTML Text Appears Over Image On Hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have been struggling for a while trying to get images to animate when I hover over them. I have found lots of examples, however I have found them difficult to implement and adjust to how I want them. Here is my code:

```css
 #box {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
   background: url("http://placehold.it/1080x720");
   background-size: cover;
 }
 #cover {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
   text-align: center;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
 }
 #box:hover #cover {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 #text {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .84);
   font-size: 60px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="cover">
    <span id="text">Comics</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My difficulty comes when setting the height, my website needs to be able to re-size the image; before I just set the width of the image (rather then a background image it is now) as 100% and it would make the height correct for the width. However now I am using a background image I cant get it to set the height automatically, it just takes the size of text that appears when you hover over.
I hope that makes sense, thanks!


EDIT
I suppose if this isn't going to work can anyone point in the way of another method that I could do the same thing?

UPDATE
This is what happened when I tried you example Kaan.

```css
#box {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
   background: url("http://placehold.it/1080x720") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 #cover {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
   text-align: center;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
 }
 #box:hover #cover {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 #text {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .84);
   font-size: 60px;
 }
#ContainerTest{
  width: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
    $("#box").css({'height': height + 'px'});
    $("#cover").css({'height': height + 'px'});
});

function resizeContent(){
    var newWidth = $(window).width();
    var newHeight = $(window).height();

    $("#box").height(newHeight).width(newWidth);
    $("#cover").height(newHeight).width(newWidth);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeContent();
});
</script>
<div id="ContainerTest">
<div id="box">
  <div id="cover">
    <span id="text">Comics</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

That did work, however I need to make myself more clear as to what I actually want it to do. You see I have a container that is 40% of the screen, I then want this image to fit inside it so you can see the whole thing by setting the width of the image to 100%, and then the height to adjust so the image is still the right height to width, so its not distorted. When you do this with a normal image it does this automatically, by just setting the width, however as its a background it does not.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell, but I think one solution might be to set `#cover` to be absolute positioned based on its parent (the parent will also need `position: relative` for this to work). If you then set `#cover` to `width: 100%; height: 100%;` it will cover its parent element.

Comment: No luck, I tried both of them, all it did was make the picture invisible for some reason? When I hovered the text still came up, but there was no image behind it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Should be easily solvable using the padding-bottom hack. Show us your attempts, instead of just saying “it didn’t work.”

Comment: From the code you have provided, it appears your issue lies in that you're not assigning a height to your `box` div. As a result, your `box` div, the div you've assigned the background image to, is only taking the height of its child elements - meaning the `font-size` of your `span` text. When will your website need to adjust the height of the image? Is the image intended to act as a background image (be covered by child elements), or do you want it to display fully on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using jQuery, you can solve this problem.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
    $("#box").css({'height': height + 'px'});
    $("#cover").css({'height': height + 'px'});
});

function resizeContent(){
    var newWidth = $(window).width();
    var newHeight = $(window).height();

    $("#box").height(newHeight).width(newWidth);
    $("#cover").height(newHeight).width(newWidth);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeContent();
});
```

You also need to change your #box css with the code below.

```
#box {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
   background: url("http://placehold.it/1080x720") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

It will work. Here is the jsfiddle link of the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/fL0n3mcj/1/